# oh-my-zsh Command Not Found: ^M

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am trying to install oh-my-zsh on Ubuntu 15. After running the installation script

```
sh -c "$(wget https://raw.github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"
```

I have the following error which never occur before

```
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:3: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:9: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:12: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:16: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:19: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:22: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:25: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:28: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:31: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:34: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:39: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:44: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:47: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:52: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:53: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:55: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:58: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:source:59: no such file or directory: /home/li-xinyang/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:60: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:63: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:70: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:73: command not found: ^M
/home/li-xinyang/.zshrc:76: command not found: ^M
```

How can I remove `^M`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is to set `autocrlf=true` to `autocrlf=false` use the command below,

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

`^M` is carriage return (CR), Windows-style text line ending make.

Answer (score 15):

In my Mac ran dos2unix for all files installed by Oh-My-Zsh. In summary it was something like below. I kept rerunning source ~/.zshrc to check if the installation was OK, without any errors, until I have converted all files, including binary files.

```
brew install dos2unix
cd /Users/<your user>/.oh-my-zsh
find . -name " *.sh" | xargs dos2unix -f
find . -name " *.zsh" | xargs dos2unix -f
dos2unix -f themes/robbyrussel.zsh-theme
cd 
dos2unix -f .zshrc
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: This answer is solution for linux users too. dos2unix solved problem

Answer (score 2):

I could resolve this error in Ubuntu by saving the file `~/.zshrc` in LF mode.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and autocrlf=true did not resolve the issue.
After I disabled the git plugin in ~/.zshrc by commenting it out, and removed & replaced the file which has the problem ^M, it was resolved. It seems git plugin on oh-my-zsh makes a conflict.

```
    #plugins=(git)
```

Comment: It probably did solve your problem and the act of replacing it changed the line endings

Comment: thanks, this worked for me !
i commented git and recloned the plugin i had problem with and it worked. i activated git again and no problem